# What is the best method to compose a set of matrices into one and then unambiguously decrypt it?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, matrix-multiplication

I am presented with the following problem:

Given a set of matrices $M = \{A^i_{m,n} : 0 < i < 101 \}$ design a procedure to compose all of them into one encrypted matrix $E_{m,n}$ and later decompose (decrypt) it into the initial set. The procedure should be as difficult to break as possible (quantum-resistant preferably). It does not need to be fast, as the message will be sent only *once* (meaning the encryption process might take hours or days with the current technology). Presumably, there will exist an encryption key $k$, which should be smaller in size than the set of matrices (as small as possible, preferably). No need for dual-key systems, one is enough for this specific problem I have in mind.

One important note: all of the elements in all of the original matrices come from $Z/nZ$ with some given $n$ (therefore they are integers: $x : 0 \leq x < n$), although this fact does not need to be used in the procedure.

Bonus points if the procedure preserves ordering of the matrices (i.e. we have a sequence $S$ instead of a set $M$). Would that be even possible?

Comment: just as curious question: Are the matrices allowed to have a certain kind of inner structure or do they need to cover all possible matrices? And are they designed in that way that every $E_{m,n}$ has only a single set/sequence of matrices as inverse solution?

Comment: @J.Doe : (1) all possible, I cannot predict what set $M$ I'll get; (2)  They are not designed in any way. It is the core of my question to come up with a method which would introduce a bijective mapping between $M$ and $E$ under given $k$

Answer (score 1):

> Given a set of matrices $M = \{A^i_{m,n} : 0 < i < 101 \}$ design a procedure to compose all of them into one encrypted matrix $E_{m,n}$ and later decompose (decrypt) it into the initial set.

The standard way to address this would be to divide this up into a three step process:

- Convert the sequence of matrices $M$ into a bit string $P$ (in an invertible way)
- Hand the bit string $P$ to a standard symmetric encryption process (e.g. AES-SIV), keyed by your secret $k$, resulting in a slightly longer bit string $C$
- Convert the bit string $C$ into the matrix $E_{m,n}$ (in an invertible way)

The decryption method should be obvious.

Yes, $E_{m,n}$ will take up as much space as all the matrices in $M$ (and actually slightly more; standard encryption methods do increase the length by a fixed amount); however any value-preserving method will has that property, so that's not that big of a deal.  You might end up making the elements within $E_{m,n}$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n^{101}$ (101 rather than 100 to account for the expansion in step 2) - since we're using the elements within $M$ only as transport, that shouldn't be that big of a deal.

And, assuming your encoding method in step 1 preserves the matrix ordering, I get the bonus points as well - I wonder what I can spend them on :-)

Comment: With 100 matrices and if $m=1000, n=1000$ and all elements are from $mod 257$ I don't really see a way to easily compress it into a bit string which would not be way too long. Besides, anything may be converted into a bitstring and then using AES we get a secure message. But this is not the merit of my questions. I was thinking more of a matrix-convolution, multiplication etc...

Comment: @max: "I don't really see a way to easily compress it into a bit string which would not be way too long"; is 100-200 Megabytes (depending on how aggressive your compression is) too long?  I believe that there are computers with that much memory.  And, this approach has the advantage of relying on well studied cryptography, which something involving matrix operations have not been.